# InfoPath Form not updating peoplepicker field on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have few people pickers on InfoPath form which are tied to the respective SharePoint List columns. Now I have to edit the people picker property to accept multiple values. I make the change in the infopath form and Publish the form. It is suppose to update the respective columns in SharePoint List but it doesn't do that.

If I try to update the SharePoint List column property to accept 'Multiple' values the form fails to load and throws this error:
"The data types of the following form fields do not match the SharePoint list: Column_name"

Can anyone tell me how should I sync the field in infopath form and SP List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the sharepoint list column property to "multiple values", open the infopath form and you should see a popup asking to update the fields. Click ok and publish the form.

If not, open the 'Data' tab in the infopath form and click on refresh fields. Publish the form and now the fields should be synced.